# Why doesn't background_page work ? Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My manifest :

```
{
"name" : "gMail Adder ",
"version" : "1.0",
"description" : "Google Chrome Gmail Adder",
"options_page": "options.html",
"background_page": "background.html",
"run_at": "document_start",
"permisions": [
   "tabs", "http://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["*://*.google.mail.com/*", "https://*.google.mail.com/*" ,"http://mail.google.com/*" ,"https://mail.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*", "http://www.google.com/*" ],
   "css": ["toggle.css"],
   "js": ["jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "inject.js", "injecter.js"]
  }
],
"browser_action" : {
"default_icon" : "Quest Icon 11.png",
"default_popup": "dialog.html"
}
}
```

My background.html() :

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert('test');
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function() {alert('hello new tab')});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

When i load the extension the **alert('test')** works once, but the **alert('hello new tab')** doesn't seem to work not even once ?

When i click a new tab why doesn't this event trigger the messagebox display ?

UPDATE: 
If i click on background.html of the extension into the **chrome://extension** page the console issues the error : "***Uncaught Error: You do not have permission to use 'tabs.onCreated'. Be sure to declare in your manifest what permissions you need.***" Why is that? All the permissions are right there in the manifest file; it shouldn't issue this error!

Comment: hm, works for me, maybe there is more code?

Comment: thanks for the response! the background.html and the MANIFEST.JSON are exactly as above! Is there maybe a security setting i should disable in order to make it work? PS : I get the same response if i delete the content_script field from the manifest.

Comment: do i need to pack the extension or leaving it unpacked will suffice?

Comment: **"permisions": [** has only two s characters instead of 3

Comment: If your problem is solved, it might be a good idea to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED :

```
"permisions": [ not
"permissions": [ YES
```

SORRY for consuming your time for no reason !

PS : Even though my english is bad shouldn't chrome's parser issue a **unidentified field** error??? Anyways, sorry!

Comment: Yes I agree, feel free to submit a bug report for this, it would be useful http://crbug.com/new

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled "**permissions**". Everything else is accurate.